# Node.js - Traceroute - Relative to server or client?

Tags: node.js, traceroute

I have a basic question on using traceroute module in **node.js**.
If we attempt to give traceroute("google.com"), does it return the results relative to client or server?

In my case, I am developing a web application where the user can do network measurements like traceroute. In such, traceroute module of node.js would return the route relative to the server where this node.js is installed or it is relative to path?

Also, Can anyone give me pointers how to use the right frameworks/technologies to build such a web app.

Thanks,
Sree